# docker service service updates stuck in updating status

Tags: docker, service, updating, swarm

We have swarm services running across two app servers. When we update the images of the services it often results in it not being rolled out to both of the servers.

The output is below, it has been trying to update for 16 hours, is there anyway to see the error log or something what might be causing it not to deploy correctly?

```
docker service inspect --pretty myservice

    ID:             6tvx7c9wjp49exv2ozpvvt8lq
Name:           myapiservice-api
Labels:
 com.df.distribute=true
 com.df.notify=true
 com.df.port=5002
 com.df.serviceDomain=mysite.net
 com.df.servicePath=/api-admin
Service Mode:   Global
UpdateStatus:
 State:         **updating**
 Started:       16 hours ago
 Message:       update in progress
Placement:
 Constraints:   [node.labels.type==appserver]
UpdateConfig:
 Parallelism:   1
 On failure:    pause
 Monitoring Period: 5s
 Max failure ratio: 0
 Update order:      stop-first
RollbackConfig:
 Parallelism:   1
 On failure:    pause
 Monitoring Period: 5s
 Max failure ratio: 0
 Rollback order:    stop-first
.....
Resources:
Networks: proxy
Endpoint Mode:  vip
```

Comment: Still ongoing issue

Comment: I'm seeing something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52260204/replicated-services-not-updating

Comment: try running `docker service update --force <service>` to see it progress, you might have a dependency or a bind issue