# Replicated services not updating

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a service which I've configured to have 3 replicas (in a swarm of 3 nodes). When it comes time to update the service to a new version, I run this:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml authentication
```

I've also tried to force an update using:

```
 docker service update --force authentication_authentication
```

One instance will get updated, the others will remain on the same version. The update command above hangs here forever:

```
overall progress: 1 out of 3 tasks 
1/3: running   [==================================================>] 
2/3:   
3/3:
```

In the systemd logs for docker, I see these entries:

```
Sep 10 10:24:28 docker01 dockerd[1478]: time="2018-09-10T10:24:28.910584651-04:00" level=warning msg="rmServiceBinding 489e7143d27eaa4e4210b080f77b60018a033b29a291599d63def87fb0bed903 possible transient state ok:false entries:0 set:false "
Sep 10 10:24:28 docker01 dockerd[1478]: time="2018-09-10T10:24:28.911078594-04:00" level=warning msg="rmServiceBinding fa961a79dc139cfcc31e7ae671b6305f83887d804c4ce28aaae6f7221de08021 possible transient state ok:false entries:0 set:false "
```

How can I get these services to update?

Additional details:

- Docker 18.06.0-ce
- Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
   authentication:
    image: "<private registry>/authentication:1.0.11"
    ports:
      - 8008:8008
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.platform.os==linux
```

Turned debug on in the docker config file and am now seeing this repeatedly in the log:

```
Sep 10 13:14:08 docker01 dockerd[1532]: time="2018-09-10T13:14:08.283136216-04:00" level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.38/nodes"
Sep 10 13:14:08 docker01 dockerd[1532]: time="2018-09-10T13:14:08.487369825-04:00" level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.38/services/authentication_authentication?insertDefaults=false"
Sep 10 13:14:08 docker01 dockerd[1532]: time="2018-09-10T13:14:08.488713081-04:00" level=debug msg="error handling rpc" error="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = service authentication_authentication not found" rpc=/docker.swarmkit.v1.Control/GetService
Sep 10 13:14:08 docker01 dockerd[1532]: time="2018-09-10T13:14:08.492766895-04:00" level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.38/tasks?filters=%7B%22_up-to-date%22%3A%7B%22true%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22service%22%3A%7B%22authentication_authentication%22%3Atrue%7D%7D"
Sep 10 13:14:08 docker01 dockerd[1532]: time="2018-09-10T13:14:08.494021275-04:00" level=debug msg="error handling rpc" error="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = service authentication_authentication not found" rpc=/docker.swarmkit.v1.Control/GetService
```

Comment: Some guesses : is your private registry still accessible from all node?
 Did you try to add the --with-registry-auth in you 'docker stack deploy/update' command? Did you check docker service ps authentificaction ? Are all your nodes running under the same version of docker (you can mix different ones)?

Comment: @Marvin - the registry is accessible from all nodes. If I remove the service and recreate it, all nodes run with the correct version of the service so I don't think it's an auth issue. Yes - checked `docker service ps`, shows a partial update (only the local node updates correctly). All nodes are running the same version of os / docker. 

Best I can tell, the issue is related to not being able to remove the service binding (rmServiceBinding errors in log).

Comment: Actually, all nodes already have a local image of previous version of the service : so it may be since this one is new. You can try to docker pull the image on each node to be sure. Doesn't mean I am right, though! I suppose you also looked at the docker inspect on both your service and containers (especially those on the remote nodes)? Also, I don't see an "error", but just a "warning" in your logs. Are some missing?

Comment: @Marvin - excellent point on that just being a warning. I went back and turned on debug for the docker service and attached some rpc errors that look related. I was also able to pull image from my private registry on the remote nodes without issue.  Nothing interesting is popping out in the inspection of the service / containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading from `18.06.0-ce` to `18.06.1-ce` resolved the issue for me.